# The ubuntu.com/community pages are getting a redo, need your help to represent Ask Ubuntu

Tags: discussion, community

If you look at the current community pages:

- http://www.ubuntu.com/community

Ask Ubuntu is mentioned in the support page in the following motivational manner:

> Ask Ubuntu
>
> http://askubuntu.com
>
> This is a collaboratively edited question and answer site for Ubuntu
>   users and developers. It's 100% free, no registration required.

This is a terrible way to describe the site. But no longer must we live in mediocrity. As part of [improving our community documentation](http://www.jonobacon.org/2012/12/09/improving-community-getting-involved-documentation/) we've tossed the whole site onto an etherpad and we're going to redo the content to be more awesome.

Instructions on each page are here:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/CommunityWebsite

Basically in the support and documentation sections we need to beef up how the community can use AU, not just point them here by a link, but point out things people can do (like Review!) to improve the quality of the site, and so on.

The etherpad pages are also in Markdown, making it easy to lift content from Meta on how-to-better-use the site and put them in a visible place. I'll be working on this on and off today, contributors more than welcome!